# AWS EB CLI (elastic beanstalk)

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed an application on EB with my own AWS account, and have done the same with another one.

I don't know how to switch out of my command line eb cli account. There are no eb CLI options to switch profiles like the normal AWS CLI...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use named profiles via `eb --profile x` to use a [specific profile](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-configuration.html#eb-cli3-profile) from your AWS credentials file.

Or you can use multiple, distinct credentials files (see [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/usingCLI.html#usingCLI.StartCLI.WhoYouAre)) and change the `AWS_CREDENTIAL_FILE` environment variable to point to the relevant credentials file. You could even write a couple of shell scripts such as `eb-project1` and `eb-project2` that each export/set the relevant `AWS_CREDENTIAL_FILE` value and then simply execute `eb` so that you don't have to switch credentials manually - just run `eb-project1` or `eb-project2` as needed instead of running `eb`.

Comment: Hey jarmod thanks for your reply! so I have set up the other profile and when typing this - "eb init --profile <name>" 
I receive this error - "ERROR: Platform 'arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:eu-west-2::platform/PHP 5.6 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.3.2' does not exist."

Comment: I've removed the advice about using eb init because it's overkill for your use case (unless you actually want to create a new EB app using the second set of credentials). Try the regular eb cli commands with the --profile option, e.g. eb list --profile xyz. Related to the failure you indicated above, see https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=164361.